# Parsing oracle SQLPLUS error message in shell script for emailing

Tags: linux, oracle, bash, awk

I'm trying to extract a substring from an Oracle error message so I can email it off to an administrator using awk, this part of the code is trying to find where the important bit I want to extract.

starts here's what I have....

(The table name is incorrect to generate the error)

```
validate_iwpcount(){

    DB_RETURN_VALUE=`sqlplus -s $DB_CRED <<END
    SELECT count(COLUMN)
    FROM INCORRECT_TABLE NAME;
    exit
    END`


    a="$DB_RETURN_VALUE"
    b="ERROR at line"
    awk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" 'BEGIN{print index(a,b)}'

    echo $DB_RETURN_VALUE

}
```

Strange thing is no matter how big that     $DB_RETURN_VALUE is the return value from awk is always 28. Im assuming that somewhere in this error message there's something linux either thinks is a implcit delimiter of somesort and its messing with the count or something stranger. This works fine with regular strings as opposed to what oracle gives me.

Could anybody shine a light on this?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you show an echoed value that awk gives the answer 28 for? For your sample I get 45, but it's tripping over `COLUMN` before it gets to the table name (ORA-00936), so it might not be representative. (Doesn't the echoed value need to be quoted to stop the `*` being expanded as a file list? Not directly relevant...)

Comment: Note that `index` does not return a substring, but the index of the substring.. So if your substring always starts at index 28, it is not so strange...

Comment: Not too sure about the star, one doesn't appear in the script. we were getting a directory list spat back at us earlier though. fixed that now. The actual string is    ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist -v b=ERROR at line BEGIN{print index(a,b)}
FROM IW_PRODUCTzS logs mail_files scripts ERROR at line 2: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: Thanks for that HH its the index I'm trying to get back although if you have a nice way of just pulling the " ERROR at line 2: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" message out of this then I'll bump some kudos your way

Comment: OK, I do get 28 with that table name, and using tabs in the script. The error message from Oracle highlight the position in the line with a `*`, which gets globbed. That's where the `logs mail_files scripts` part is coming from, not from Oracle. Always wrapping in double-quotes stops the globbing.

Comment: I do not have `sqlplus` installed, could give a sample of what you feed into awk through the `$a` variable?

Comment: Alex thats a point I wasnt aware of tbh and might well be the culprit but theres no way of chopping it up and escaping them for the script i dont think. HH b="ERROR at line", but if the above is the cause this might be a lost cause

Comment: It easy to extract substrings with `awk`, just give an example of the `$a` that you feed awk with, and what substring you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`28` seems to be the right answer for the query you have (slightly amended to avoid an ORA-00936, and with tabs in the script). The message you're echoing includes a file expansion; the raw message is:

```
        FROM IW_PRODUCTzS
             *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

The `*` is expanded when you `echo $DB_RETURN_VALUE`, so the directory you're executing this from seem to have `logs mail_files scripts` in it, and they are being shown through expansion of the `*`. If you run it from different directories the *echoed* message length will vary, but the length of the actual message from Oracle stays the same - the length is changing (through the expansion) after the SQL*Plus call and after `awk` has done its thing.  You can avoid that expansion with `echo "$DB_RETURN_VALUE"` instead, though I don't suppose you actually want to see that full message anyway in the end.

The substring from character 28 gives you what you want though:

```
validate_iwpcount(){

    DB_RETURN_VALUE=`sqlplus -s $CENSYS_ORACLE_UID <<END
    SELECT count(COLUMN_NAME)
    FROM IW_PRODUCTzS;
    exit
    END`

    # To see the original message; note the double-quotes
    # echo "$DB_RETURN_VALUE"

    a="$DB_RETURN_VALUE"
    b="ERROR at line"
    p=`awk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" 'BEGIN{print index(a,b)}'`

    if [ ${p} -gt 0 ]; then
        awk -v a="$a" -v p="$p" 'BEGIN{print substr(a,p)}'
    fi

}

validate_iwpcount
```

... displays just:

```
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I'm sure that can be simplified, maybe into a single `awk` call, but I'm not that familiar with it.

Comment: I hear what your saying Alex, the bit I'm emailing is just the bit that was asked for. tbh they weren't even sure that was necessary. Ill get your solution into code in the morning and let you know how it goes. Cheers!

Comment: @PeterDonoghue - fair enough, can't argue with requirements, but thought it was worth querying. I'll remove that part since it isn't really relevant.

Comment: I didn't argue at the time either bud :) That extra bit code is exactly what I was looking for Alex, many thanks for your help!